# Follow the link from href as a callback

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link `<a href="/preview/3" target="_blank">Preview</a>`. I want to control it with jQuery like this:

```
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        savePage(previewPage);
    });
```

With `savePage` function I save some data then run a preview in a new window by executing `window.open` as a callback. I face a problem with this because browsers block my window popping up. So I just want to follow that link after `savePage` finishes.
How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Use a callback inside `savePage`. Inside your callback, you'll change `document.location` to use the value of the link's `href`. Since you'll back calling your callback from within `savePage` (preferably at the end), the browser won't go to the new location until `savePage` finishes running: So your code will look like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
      var link = this;
      savePage(previewPage, function() {
          document.location = link.href;
      });
      return false;
});
```

Within `savePage`, make sure you call your callback:

```
function savePage(previewPage, callback) {
   ...
   ...

   if(typeof callback !== "undefined") {
      callback.call(null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually pop-up blockers will only block a pop-up that is outside of your host. If you are trying to open a window that is outside your host i.e. http://example.com <- Your host & http://www.anothersite.com/popup.php <- outside your host.

If this is the case then I suggest creating a blank.htm file, or something of the sort, and putting an iframe in it.